# Login or Register Segmented Control Button

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uisegmentedcontrol

I currently have login / register button working with segmented controls. I am trying to use the button login to use the handleLogin function, and the register button to use the handleRegister function. I currently try to call these functions this way, but no luck.
 My code is below:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            nameTextField.isHidden = true
            universityTextField.isHidden = true
            universityDropDown.isHidden = true
            loginRegisterButton.setTitle("Login", for: UIControlState())
            loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
        case 1:
            universityTextField.isHidden = false
            nameTextField.isHidden = false
            loginRegisterButton.setTitle("Register", for: UIControlState())
            loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should have one method connected to the button and inside the method you decide whether to call register or login based on segmented control selected index

Comment: The code was correct. set breakpoint to catch the issue.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S the segmented control does not know that it is at index 0 when the app first launches, I need to click register then click back on login for it to work...

Comment: @Phyber the segmented control does not know that it is at index 0 when the app first launches

Comment: You can set selected index to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can write separate function for changing interface according to `selectedIndex` of the `UISegmentedControl`. Also, you need only one `Target` to perform particular action. So, before adding a target you need to remove other all targets. Else you will get multiple actions at a time of pressing the `loginRegisterButton`.

```
func changeInterfaceAccoringto(_ index:Int){

    /*Remove all targets before add*/
    loginRegisterButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)

    switch index {
    case 0:
        nameTextField.isHidden = true
        universityTextField.isHidden = true
        universityDropDown.isHidden = true
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle("Login", for: UIControlState())
        loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
    case 1:
        universityTextField.isHidden = false
        nameTextField.isHidden = false
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle("Register", for: UIControlState())
        loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

call `changeInterfaceAccoringto` at `indexChanged` like as below,

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    changeInterfaceAccoringto(loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

For changing Interface at ideal you need to call `changeInterfaceAccoringto` in method `viewDidLoad` like as below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /*Change UISegmentedControl selected index at ideal if you want*/
    //loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1

    changeInterfaceAccoringto(loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Let me know is that you need?

Comment: @FrankBoccia , Actually you did not called `indexChanged` statements on `viewDidLoad()`. That is the problem